# Could not show content of a table in SQL server to C# Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I want to show content of a table("newexample") in my database in SQL server to gridview in ASP.net, but the gridview shows nothing. How to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleDBCS"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from newexample", con);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("col0");
            dt.Columns.Add("col1");
            dt.Columns.Add("col2");

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["col0"] = rdr["col0"];
                dr["col1"] = rdr["col1"];
                dr["col2"] = rdr["col2"];

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            con.Close();

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you please add code of page?

Comment: this code is working fine there must be something wrong with page

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any exception? Try moving `con.Close()` after `DataBind()` and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code below:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("newexample");
SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from newexample", connectionString);
dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);


   if (dataSet != null)
   {
    if (dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = dataSet ;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = null;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

This is a better approach since `SqlDataAdapter` will take care for `SqlConnection`. It is responsible to create the connection and to close it at the end of operation in the best way possible.

This is not a tested code so if you have any problem let me know..

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rajmond Burgaj, but the gridview also shows nothing. I am not sure for this: DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("newexample"); or maybe there is a problem with the connection to my database.